# Add months difference to new date

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime

For an application I need to do some calculations with dates. I found how I can get the difference in months between 2 dates but not how I can add these months to another date.

**Function to calculate difference in months:**

```
public static decimal GetMonthsInRange(DateTime start, DateTime finish)
{
    var monthsApart = 
        Math.Abs(12 * (start.Year - finish.Year) + start.Month - finish.Month) - 1;

    decimal daysInStartMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(start.Year, start.Month);
    decimal daysInFinishMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(finish.Year, finish.Month);

    var daysApartInStartMonth = (daysInStartMonth - start.Day + 1) / daysInStartMonth;
    var daysApartInFinishMonth = finish.Day / daysInFinishMonth;

    return monthsApart + daysApartInStartMonth + daysApartInFinishMonth;
}
```

**Example:**

The difference in months I get is 4.5 months and I need to add that to another date. But the `DateTime.AddMonths` function only accepts integer numbers.

How can I do this?

Grts,
Nanou

Comment: Months are *differ* they are `28-31` days in range. Is it possible to convert `4.5` months into days? If yes, `.AddDays(days);`

Comment: Indeed - basically you need to be more precise in what you mean. For example, if you add 1.5 months to January 1st 2017, do you want that to be Feb 15th (because February has 28 days in 2017) or Feb 16th/17th (because January has 31 days)? Calendar math is a fiddly business - you need to be *really, really* clear about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Tbh @JonSkeet I don't have an answer for that. I'm going to try and see if I can get it working with calculating the days.

Comment: Blatant plug :Once you've worked out what you want to do, my Noda Time library (http://nodatime.org) may well make it easier to express that.

Comment: I used ur library for something else but could not get it working for my question.

Comment: Well without knowing what you want the result to be, I'm not surprised. That's why I'm urging you to carefully consider what you're trying to achieve first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously, you should not calculate difference in months if you want to add this difference to some `DateTime` since this difference can be even more confusing, say 4.33 months or something like this.

Instead - just calculate difference in days (in your concrete example it will be `(finish - start).TotalDays`) and use `AddDays`.

Comment: Do you have a way of calculating the difference in days?

Comment: @Nanou Ponette: `int days = (finish - start).TotalDays;` or alike

Answer (score 0):

The DateTime has "AddMonths" and "AddDays" functions among others. These take integer values. If you have fractional months, you should preserved the integer difference in days that you worked out and add that value as days for the required accuracy.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx

Also, you do have a problem because you're doing ABS calculations for months apart (so that it works both ways), but you don't seen to be making the same before/after corrections for the days in the month calcuations.

Answer (score 0):

Your `GetMonthsInRange` works like this: each day is counted with a weight *inversely proportional* to the number of days in the month. So the *same time difference* of one day (i.e. 24 hours) - if it falls in a *different* month - corresponds to *different* decimal results, according to your *strange* rule of `GetMonthsInRange`.

I'm saying that it is strange, but maybe one could have some *contractual/accounting* reasons to redefine the difference in months. Like for example if one want to compute a *time-equivalent* period based on a *monthly amount*...

If you want to have the reverse engineered `AddMonths`, based on the same rule, so to be *consistent* with that position, you could write an extension like the following

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static DateTime AddMonths(this DateTime date, decimal months)
    {
        var start = date;
        decimal daysInStartMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(start.Year, start.Month);
        var daysApartInStartMonth = (daysInStartMonth - start.Day + 1) / daysInStartMonth;
        if (months <= daysApartInStartMonth)
        {
            return date.AddDays((double)(months * daysInStartMonth - 1));
        }
        var finish = date.AddMonths(1);
        int monthsApart = 0;
        if (months > daysApartInStartMonth + 1)
        {
            monthsApart = (int)(months - daysApartInStartMonth);
            finish = finish.AddMonths(monthsApart);

        }
        decimal daysInFinishMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(finish.Year, finish.Month);
        var startOfFinishMonth = new DateTime(finish.Year, finish.Month, 1).AddDays(-1);
        decimal remaining = months - daysApartInStartMonth - monthsApart;
        return startOfFinishMonth.AddDays((double)(remaining * daysInFinishMonth));
    }
}
```

Test if this fits your needs. I assume you want `GetMonthsInRange` and `AddMonths` to be consistent.

A possible test case generator

```
        bool ok = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            var day1 = new DateTime(2017, 2, 16);
            var day2 = new DateTime(2017, 2, 16).AddDays(i);
            var test = Extensions.GetMonthsInRange(day1, day2);
            var res = day1.AddMonths(test);
            var check = DateTime.Compare(day2, res);
            if (check != 0)
            {
                ok = false;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can try using *linear interpolation* between *two* `AddMonth` results:

```
private static DateTime AddMonths(DateTime source, double months) {
  int left = (int) Math.Floor(months);
  int right = (int) Math.Ceiling(months);

  double days = 
     (source.AddMonths(right) - source.AddMonths(left)).TotalDays * 
     (months - Math.Floor(months));

  return source.AddMonths(left).AddDays(days);
}
```

Tests:

```
DateTime source = DateTime.Today;
double add = 1.0;

Console.Write($"{source} + {add} = {AddMonths(source, add)}");

add = 1.1;
Console.Write($"{source} + {add} = {AddMonths(source, add)}");

add = 1.5;
Console.Write($"{source} + {add} = {AddMonths(source, add)}");

add = 1.95;
Console.Write($"{source} + {add} = {AddMonths(source, add)}");

add = 2.0;
Console.Write($"{source} + {add} = {AddMonths(source, add)}");
```

Outcome:

```
16.02.2017 0:00:00 + 1    = 16.03.2017  0:00:00
16.02.2017 0:00:00 + 1.1  = 19.03.2017  2:24:00
16.02.2017 0:00:00 + 1.5  = 31.03.2017 12:00:00
16.02.2017 0:00:00 + 1.95 = 14.04.2017 10:48:00 
16.02.2017 0:00:00 + 2    = 16.04.2017  0:00:00
```

However, remember, months have different lengths `[28..31]` days, and *interpolation* is just *estimation*.